# Netplan Doesn't Recognize Ethernet Connection on Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ethernet, netplan

**Problem**

I've recently moved an Ubuntu 20.04 server to a new house and attempted to connect it to the network. Connecting it via an ethernet cable at my previous house worked without issue, but doing so with my new modem isn't working. After confirming the ethernet cable works with my laptop, I started debugging and came to the conclusion that I've configured something incorrectly with netplan.

**Attempt at a Solution**

Running `$ ip a` initially produced the following output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:b1:56:dc:47:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br-cd5031a2a690: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:88:f5:00:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.29.0.1/16 brd 172.29.255.255 scope global br-cd5031a2a690
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:63:c5:ed:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-6e210ada6a5d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:cc:35:23:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.0.1/16 brd 172.30.255.255 scope global br-6e210ada6a5d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:ccff:fe35:238d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-75e07944c75a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:cb:38:ca:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.27.0.1/16 brd 172.27.255.255 scope global br-75e07944c75a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:cbff:fe38:ca3c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: veth5501abf@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-6e210ada6a5d state UP group default 
    link/ether 3e:9d:7d:bc:07:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::3c9d:7dff:febc:75f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth5f8842d@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-75e07944c75a state UP group default 
    link/ether f2:f4:e9:50:51:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::f0f4:e9ff:fe50:51ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: veth6164405@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-6e210ada6a5d state UP group default 
    link/ether 5e:f2:e1:fd:1f:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::5cf2:e1ff:fefd:1f4d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: veth8f9aa5b@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-6e210ada6a5d state UP group default 
    link/ether 46:c8:0b:f7:c5:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::44c8:bff:fef7:c5ac/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: vethc256b04@if15: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-75e07944c75a state UP group default 
    link/ether b6:7c:3e:1e:ec:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::b47c:3eff:fe1e:ec7e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This indicated to me that `eno1` is the interface I need to fix; all the bridges and veth interfaces are likely from Docker containers I run.

I then set my `01-netcfg.yaml` file to the following recommended configuration to setup a connection with a dynamic DHCP-assigned IP:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
```

and ran the following:

`$ sudo netplan --debug generate`

`$ sudo netplan apply`

`$ sudo reboot`

The debug output from the 'generate' command spit out the following:

```
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.020: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: starting new processing pass
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: eno1: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: Generating output files..
** (generate:4699): DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: NetworkManager: definition eno1 is not for us (backend 1)
(generate:4699): GLib-DEBUG: 04:02:19.021: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

The `NetworkManager: definition eno1 is not for us` seems to be an issue, and after rebooting I still can't ping anything:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

I repeated the above steps using this recommended `01-netcfg.yaml` config instead, and confirmed that I'm using spaces instead of tabs and that my spacing is correct:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Running the same setup commands with the debug flag yields this output:

```
** (generate:5041): DEBUG: 04:09:33.721: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:5041): DEBUG: 04:09:33.721: starting new processing pass
** (generate:5041): DEBUG: 04:09:33.721: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:5041): DEBUG: 04:09:33.721: Generating output files..
(generate:5041): GLib-DEBUG: 04:09:33.721: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)
```

which no longer has the concerning `NetworkManager: definition eno1 is not for us` message (since `eno1` wasn't specified), but after applying these generated changes and rebooting I still get no connection.

I've followed a number of posts and guides that seem to recommend variations of these two configs, but one that I strongly believe had the same issue I'm experiencing is [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258207/how-to-restore-a-working-network-configuration-with-netplan-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Here the poster notes that part of the problem was from a bug in kernel 5.4.0-42-generic, which was resolved by installing the `r8168-dkms` driver. I am also running kernel 5.4.0-42-generic, and manually installed this driver / updated initramfs but still had no luck after rebooting and retrying both of the above netplan configurations.

Additionally, here is my output from running `$ sudo lshw -class network` if that helps:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: f8:b1:56:dc:47:25
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:25 memory:f7c00000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c39000-f7c39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: br-75e07944c75a
       serial: 02:42:cb:38:ca:3c
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.27.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: veth5f8842d
       serial: f2:f4:e9:50:51:ac
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vethc256b04
       serial: b6:7c:3e:1e:ec:7e
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: br-6e210ada6a5d
       serial: 02:42:cc:35:23:8d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.30.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: veth5501abf
       serial: 3e:9d:7d:bc:07:5f
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: br-cd5031a2a690
       serial: 02:42:88:f5:00:c2
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.29.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:6
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:63:c5:ed:bf
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:7
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: veth6164405
       serial: 5e:f2:e1:fd:1f:4d
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:8
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       logical name: veth8f9aa5b
       serial: 46:c8:0b:f7:c5:ac
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

**Request**

Would anyone be able to help me fix this issue with Netplan and get ethernet working on my server again? I really appreciate your help, if there is any additional information you need from me please feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

The output showing `NetworkManager: definition eno1 is not for us` was correct; it simply tells you that this interface is being handled by the `networkd` backend and not the `NetworkManager` one.  When you removed the references to `eno1` from your yaml, you told netplan not to configure any interfaces, which is not what you want.

And your `ip a` output shows that the `eno1` interface is listed as `NO-CARRIER`.  This generally indicates your hardware is capable of link detection and in this case has detected that there is no link.  So you may need to try a different ethernet cable, verify that your cable is well-seated, and try connecting to a device other than your modem to check that it's not a modem problem.