# Restoring network connection in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager

I use laptop thinkpad e14 with dockstation 40AY0090EU.
Wired ethernet is connected to the dockstation.

OS is ubuntu 22.04, wm is KDE.

The problem is this - I occasionally deleted this wired connection via GUI and now it is not working. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0):

I run Kubuntu myself and had to seek out this very thing. I feel your pain. I think you will find this ["How to restore a working network configuration with netplan on Ubuntu 20.04"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258207/ddg#1258291)very helpful. I realize that is not quite your version, but I have found things like this especially with Kubuntu, not sure why, but anyway, I am unsure why it is a bit lengthy, but this is the one that has helped me in the past. May it do to you likewise, my friend. Happy Coding!

MichaelTheGamer